# Validation on multiple inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I have a number of inputs that are added dynamically via a plus and a minus sign.
All of these inputs will be added within the div encdomlocal. Im using the following code to validate the input and then add the css, but its not working as expected. i.e it only validates the first input box within the div.

```
$('#encdomlocal input:nth-child(2)').blur(function() {
    var REGEX = /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$/;
if (REGEX.test($("#encdomlocal input:nth-child(2)").val())) {
  $(this).removeClass();
  $(this).addClass("good");
} 
    else {
      $(this).removeClass();
      $(this).addClass("bad");
   }
});
```

Any help would be great, thanks....

Comment: `input:nth-child(2)` that's the 2nd input... Ins't it?

Comment: @Lix - `:nth-child` starts from 1 not 0, but still I think this could be the problem...

Comment: could possibly help: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @nnn - yea - saw that a second after :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate for your dynamically created inputs
if using jQuery 1.7+ then use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('blur','#encdomlocal input:nth-child(2)',function() {
```

Else you can use [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) jquery 1.6 and lower

```
$(document).delegate('#encdomlocal input:nth-child(2)','blur',function() {
```

`document` can be replaced with any parent element

UPDATE:

```
if (REGEX.test($(this).val())) { //<-- I don't know what you were testing but using $(this) works here
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("good");
}
else {
    $(this).removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("bad");
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9DW8f/9/

You were using

```
if (REGEX.test($("#encdomlocal input:nth-child(2)").val()))
```

it was returning a set of elements so you weren't testing the current textbox that fired the `blur` event

> The jQuery Object: The Wrapped Set: Selectors return a jQuery object known as the "wrapped set," which is an array-like structure that contains all the selected DOM elements. You can iterate over the wrapped set like an array or access individual elements via the indexer ($(sel)[0] for example). More importantly, you can also apply jQuery functions against all the selected elements.<

If you are going to be using the same REGEX you can just add the other selector by separating with comma

```
$("#encdomlocal").on("blur", "input:nth-child(2),otherSelector",//<--- use this if regex for validation is the same
```

If you are using a new regex you can just use

```
$(document).on('blur','otherSelector',function() {
    // validation code goes here.  You can pretty much copy the other one and change the regex to what you need
});
```

Comment: How about `$("#encdomlocal").on("blur","input:nth-child(2)", ...`

Comment: Thanks all, but ive tried the suggestions but im not getting the intended results. You can see this here : http://jsfiddle.net/9DW8f/6/
The first column of check boxes should validate based on IP (i.e 8.8.8.8).

Comment: @felix001 Added an updated fiddle and updated my answer for you

Comment: Ah great thanks. Brilliant explanation as well. One last thing how would I add another div input to validate ?

Comment: @felix001 Are you talking about the CHECKB column now?  And is it going to be the same REGEX validation?

Comment: @wirey It will be just a single input within another div. Ive updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9DW8f/11/. Thanks again.

Comment: @felix001  It should be easy for you.  I updated my answer to show you how to do it.  I don't know what your validating for so I gave you two ways to do it depending on what you are validating

Comment: @wirey Thanks yep that seems to make sense. Though for 
`$("#encdomlocal").on("blur", "input:nth-child(2),otherSelector",//<--- use this if regex for validation is the same
`
How would you add another selector if it was in another div. Im just trying to cut down on the amount of code that I need.

Comment: @felix001 All you have to do is give the div an id or a class so you can select it.  For example `<div id='otherSelector>input box's</div>` then you can just use `$(document).on("blur", "input:nth-child(2),#otherSelector",function(){` <-- notice I changed it to document since it's a guarantee parent of all elements.  You can change it to $('body') or any parent element that will cover the ones you need

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13488/discussion-between-felix001-and-wirey)